# Multiple IDs and Multiple passwords for single Wireless i.e Wifi Network

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a wireless WiFi at a paying guest accommodation, and have atleast 50 people. I need to connect multiple users with their own Id and their passwords for the same router for internet access. To do this what should I do? Can use the same wifi router? should I look for something different? Do i need a new type of setup? Please help.

Comment: I gave a answer that covers this fairly well at the question for  [Providing passwords to multiple users on a wi-fi network](http://superuser.com/questions/383701/providing-passwords-to-multiple-users-on-a-wi-fi-network)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like answering some of your questions:

https://serverfault.com/questions/192905/whats-the-maximum-number-of-wifi-connections-for-a-single-wifi-router

so, basically: probably you can forget 50 connections to one single AP.
Since Wifi Router are so cheap you probably want to setup some more of them.

As for the authentication part, you could use a captive portal (aka Hotspot) as described here: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot

cheers, t.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hans Meiser and would like to add that is quite the business venture you have there! Even at a dollar a piece, you have your internet service plan paid for! lol

Anyway, the best way to accomplish your goal is to create a server on a computer, preferably win server 2003. this allows you to create the users however you would like. attach access point to server. keep the wifi signal the same, also authentication of guest account the same for all users. once the users connect to access point successfully, the will have to further authenticate using username and password that is created on server.

this type of setup is alot more involved but will accomplish exactly what you are asking and also alot more versatile!